# error TS2322: Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'NgIterable<any>'

Tags: typescript, iteration, ngfor, angular14

I've created a custom component for my data table. The same component works fine in other projects with `Angular < 14.` Since I've update Angular to v14 I got the errors below.

In the `ts`file, this is how I declare `tableData`

```
//imports...

@Component({
  selector: 'fq-table',
  templateUrl: './fq-table.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./fq-table.component.scss'],

})
export class FqTableComponent implements OnInit {
 @Input() tableData: any[] = [];
....
}
```

This is my `NgModule`

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    FqTableComponent,
    FqInputComponent,
    NotFoundComponent,
    FqPaginationPipe,
    ....
  ],
  providers: [ThemeService],
  imports: [
    NgbModule,
    CommonModule,
    BrowserModule,
    RouterModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    FormsModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MatTooltipModule,
    ....
  ],
  exports : [
    NgbModule,
    CommonModule,
    BrowserModule,
    RouterModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    FormsModule,
  
  /**
    * CUSTOM COMPONENTS
    */
    FqTableComponent,
    FqInputComponent,
    NotFoundComponent,
    /**
     * PIPE
     */
    FqPaginationPipe
  ]
})
export class SharedModule { }
```

The HTML code
[image]

Here is the error i get when I want to compile the project.

[image]

Comment: What type does the `fqPagination` pipe return? I suspect it returns `unknown`.

Comment: @JSONDerulo `fqPagination ` returns an `array of any`